# Attaching cells changes homology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space, what are the possible effects on homology by attaching a $1$-dimensional cell to $X$ along a map $f: S^0 \to X$?

I think it is wise to consider the two cases where the points of $S^0$ are in the same path component or not but from here I don't really know, it might be the wrong approach.

I think the answer to the above can be used to answer the following next exercise: what the possible homology groups of a space obtained from $S^2 \coprod S^1 \coprod S^0$  by attaching three $1$-dimensional cells?

I think by biggest problem is that I don't have a geometrical interpretation of cells attachments, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take the trivial case- what's the meaning of 0th homology??

Comment: Use Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  not quite sure what the second exercise asks for, would you mind explaining?